# Limiting the maximum and minimum values of an interpolation surface tool (ArcGIS, Spline)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, interpolation, arcgis-desktop, spline

I've been using the spatial analyst spline tool in ArcGIS 10.1 and was wandering whether it is possible to limit the maximum and minimum values to those of the z-attribute.
Currently the spline will exceed both these values.

Comment: I don't believe ArcGIS supports that kind of spline.  The [help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Spline_works/009z00000078000000/) suggests you try the "tension" option and explains that increasing the value of its parameter will eventually do what you want, at the cost of producing a rougher interpolated surface.

Comment: are there any updates on this issue? can we set limits to interpolation?